# Sending mail from vps that receives forwarder trafic from another provider

Tags: email, domain, vps

Currently, I utilize two hosting providers: one has shared hosting and here I registered domains, another has one vps server.

I redirect requests to my.site.com from shared server to vps using record A.
As a result, my website is accessible, but I cannot send mail correctly, because these mails have wrong header  Received: from vpshostname.localdomain (unknown [xx.xx.xx.xx]), where xx.xx.xx.xx means server IP.

Is it possible to configure my vps to send mails for my example, or I should transfer my my.site.com to vps and then configure it properly ?

I would like not to transfer my domain.

Comment: What kind of website?  WordPress?  Who hosts your email,  who's your VPS provider?

Comment: https://www.ukraine.com.ua/ hosts my emails, https://contabo.com/ provides me with vps. Is CMS important ? CMS just uses mail service, now I try to send mails from webmin.

Comment: CMS is easier for some to configure for email authentication, like wordpress has https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/ but I'll give you a system wide answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options, relay off your mail host with credentials or run a mailserver on your VPS:

install and configure postfix:

`mkdir /etc/ssl/private/
openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/postfix.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem`

enter the real hostname you will be using for ehlo when prompted for the common name, this ensures TLS matches when sending email.

`chmod o= /etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem`

Configure Postfix:
  `postconf -e smtpd_use_tls=yes
  postconf -e smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/postfix.pem
  postconf -e smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem
  postconf -e smtpd_tls_loglevel=3
  postconf -e smtpd_tls_received_header=yes
  postconf -e smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout=3600s
  postconf -e tls_random_source=dev:/dev/urandom`
`

**Check if you can send email** 
telnet to an mx server, `telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25`
if you get a 220 response you are good, if not YOU MUST USE AUTH.

1) Authenticated Relay Configuration

  `postconf -e relayhost=smtp.example.com:submission
  postconf -e smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  postconf -e smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
  postconf -e smtp_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  postconf -e smtp_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous`

`echo 'smtp.example.com username:password' >> /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`

2) Mail host
As a mail host, you need to configure SPF at the least, DKIM and DMARC if you are doing bulk mail or want email authentication.  You'll need access to your DNS:

`@ IN TXT "v=spf1 a mx ip4:x.x.x.x -all`

Then reconfigure your host to send accordingly.

Other Stuff) 
You can re-map your from name with generic maps

`postconf -e smtp_generic_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/generic`

`echo 'www-data no-reply@example.com' >> /etc/postfix/generic
  echo 'root no-reply@example.com' >> /etc/postfix/generic
  postmap /etc/postfix/generic
  service postfix restart`

As always when changing `postconf -e` values, watch `tail -f /var/log/maillog` and use `postfix reload`

Other excellent info, https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix

Comment: I get 220 mx.google.com ESMTP m12si10411712wmg.108 - gsmtp and HELO
250 mx.google.com at your service. However, still cannot send messages in Webmin Mail queue I see host mx15.ukraine.com.ua[91.222.136.248] said: 450 4.7.1 <vpshostname.localdomain>: Helo command rejected: Host not found (in reply to RCPT TO command). I guess that when I send email, it is sent the Helo message, and then server sends back server's Helo message that is received by ukraine.com.ua.  Now I'm reading about Mail servers and think that I should configure a MX-record and may be DNS as well.